# How to use OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS in a Pod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Has anybody tried to use build configuration flags in a Swift based Pod? I am trying to use a [post_install](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#post_install) hook to add "OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS" to a private Swift pod that I'm working on. Basically, I want to be able to do something like `#if DEV #elseif QA #else #endif` to change endpoints based on the target that I'm using. The project I'm integrating the pod with also uses DEV & QA flags which work fine with corresponding DEV & QA targets.

Here is a post_install hook that I came up using help from other similar posts:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == 'Pods-Test-QA'
            puts "Found #{target.name}. Adding Swift Flag..."
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                puts "Configuration: #{config}"
                config.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
                config.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] << '-DQA'
                puts "#{config.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'].inspect}"
            end
        end
        if target.name == 'Pods-Test-DEV'
            puts "Found #{target.name}. Adding Swift Flag..."
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                puts "Configuration: #{config}"
                config.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
                config.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] << '-DDEV'
                puts "#{config.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'].inspect}"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

After running `pod install` the post_install successfully adds the flags as shown in the image below for Pods-Test-QA & Pods-Test-DEV.

[image]

However, when I run the project using QA or DEV targets and use the following flags it always hits PROD:

```
#if DEV
    print("DEV ENVIRONMENT")
#elseif QA
    print("QA ENVIRONMENT")
#else
    print("PROD ENVIRONMENT")
#endif
```

Is there something I'm missing?
Also, for some reason `Pods-Test-QA.debug.xcconfig` & `DEV` don't seem to be updated with the flags I've added. Does anyone have any idea why it's not updating in the .xcconfig files?

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = $(inherited) "-D" "COCOAPODS"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Using:

- cocoapods (1.0.1)
- Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: Hello mate, did you manage to do it?

Comment: @thibautnoah I wasn't able to figure it out :(. I ended up removing the swift flag based logic and just used environment variables that I passed to the pod.

Comment: I managed to do it, there you go mate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44949852/access-parent-project-other-swift-flags-from-pod/44950831#44950831

Answer (score 2):

If you develop your own pod and would like to add some flags depending on the configuration you can do so by mentioning it in your *podspec* file.

My goal was to add '*BETA*' flag to my pod if parent's project active configuration contains 'BETA' in its name without post-install hooks.

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS[config=*Beta*]' => '-DBETA',
}
```

Podspec not only allows to do add custom flags but gives an opportunity to use wildcards.

The result: if my parent project uses '*Extra Early Beta*' configuration then the following fork in pod's sources goes to 'BETA'

```
        #if BETA
        // Beta related code
        #else
        // Code I don't need in beta.
        #endif
```